# How do I use bind Viewmodels to bottomTabbed Viewpages in xamarin.forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am using ViewModel.AutoWireViewmodel. So the tabbed view is already bound to a viewmodel. I don't know how bind my respective pages to their respective viewmodels

Answer (score 0):

If you have bound your `TabbedPage` to a ViewModel, you can do it the same way for your other pages. Each page also has a `BindingContext`, so set each pages `BindingContext` to the ViewModel needed for each page.

**MyPage1.cs Constructor:**

```
public MyPage1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    BindingContext = new MyPage1ViewModel();
}
```